# What is a secure choice for an internet facing web server in Java?

Tags: java, security, webserver

I need implement a server that is publicly accessible from the internet. The server has a very simple mission:

- Accept form POSTs from users over HTTPS (the actual HTML form is on a different site)
- Rewrite the form post as JSON
- Send it to an internal server over separate HTTPS connection, with multi server fail-over
- Wait for a reply in JSON, containing either success or a error reason
- Return a '303' redirection from either to a success URI or a failure URI, putting the error reason as a query parameter

The load this server is normally subjected to is minimal, but since there are no access restrictions, the server can obviously be attacked by DOS etc.

However, the real issue here is that security is absolutely paramount for the server - the server is involved in payment transactions with a large enough volume to make it a desirable target for cracking. The server is behind an IPS, but is otherwise directly connected to the internet and will terminate the HTTPS connections from end-user browsers directly without any intervening reverse proxies or SSL accelerators or such.

So, my question is, which Java web server would be the safest choice for such a purpose?

Or, alternatively, if you really think such requests should not directly be received by Java, but by lighttpd or something else, you may propose something else. But only if it can fulfill the requirements given above.

---

A really nice answer would touch on these issues:

- Relevant security of OpenSSL vs. Java crypto vs. alternatives (all have had vulnerabilities)
- Relevant security of Java VM features (such as recent XML parsing vulnerability)
- Relevant security of web server's HTTP header parsing (almost all seem to have had vulnerabilities there)
- Relevant security of optional compression (zlib has had vulnerabilities and mod_deflate has had separate vulnerabilities on top of that)

Comment: While mutual fund managers are quick to point out that past performance is no indicator of future performance, you can check the security history on the tools you are considering in the [CVE](http://cve.mitre.org/cve/) list. It only lists bugs that are publicly known, of course, and a small project no-one knows about (and thus doesn't have many publicly known bugs) may be nothing but a walking pile of coincidentally working code. But I find CVE a very useful tool. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm am aware of CVE and the information I can find there. I'm looking for more erudite answers than I can come up with half a day of google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd argue that your main concern should be following best security practices and keeping your software up to date than specifically which software you choose. It's just about impossible to predict future vulnerabilities. And software with a lot of past vulnerabilities doesn't necessarily mean it was less secure, likely it was targeted more often and thus fixed more often. In that regard you want software that is regularly updated and you have an easy way to routinely get those updates.

I'd suggest Tomcat and follow the steps from [Improving Apache Tomcat Security](http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-security). Tomcat has the benefit of being common and open source, so it gets a lot of attention and quick fixes. Many attacks are against things you don't even need, so disable everything you can. Configure your web.xml to only accept URL paths you expect and give an error for everything else.

It doesn't sound like you need Apache HTTPD in front of the web container. It's probably best then to reduce the number of attack vectors and have web requests go directly to the web container. It's not possible to know which of HTTPD or Java are going to have more vulnerabilities discovered for SSL and gzip. Yet if you use only Java then you're at least not open to the rest of what might be found for HTTPD, versus a limited set of native implementation concerns for Java.

Make sure Java and your web container are kept up to date. Network and OS hardening should be researched too, if they haven't been. You might also want to look into daily scanning for web vulnerabilities to stay on top of new threats.

Comment: All the other security aspects are being handled as well. On top of that, the service is getting PCI certified by a QSA. Thank you for your answer. However, "Tomcat handling SSL and gzip is more secure because of Java" is somewhat misleading as both SSL and gzip are implemented with C implementations in Java, as opposed to pure Java. zlib vulnerabilities causing remote code execution were just as valid for Java as other implementations. Using PureTLS and JZlib could actually achieve the Java security promise.

Comment: Since the needs are quite limited, I don't need most of Tomcats features and will have to make sure they are disabled. Where as Jetty follows a somewhat more modular approach which allows excluding entirely the code that isn't needed. Would you consider this as important point? Could it tip the balance between Jetty and Tomcat?

Comment: For Tomcat vs Jetty that's a good point. It's not too hard to disable things in Tomcat though, and there would still be things to disable in Jetty if you use a standard deployment. However you might want to consider embedding Jetty and programmatically initializing. I've done that before, it's fairly easy, and then you'd only explicitly be starting what you need. Their security report at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+Security doesn't have many issues listed, so they either really don't have many or they're not being found and fixed as often as Tomcat.

Comment: You're right, it does appear that both SSL and gzip are native implementations for Java to make them faster. In that case it'd probably be safest to get a hardware end point to do SSL, and likely you can get it to do gzip as well.

Comment: Getting a hardware endpoint for SSL is not an option for us. We are limited somewhat as to what hardware the hoster will get if we ask for something - and hardware endpoints for SSL end up being embedded Linux boxes where the SSL is implemented with OpenSSL. The end result is not more security, it's less security.

Comment: Indeed hardware endpoints are just Linux with OpenSSL. I updated my answer to correct what you pointed out about native implementations of SSL and gzip in Java, nice catch. I'd still lean toward serving web requests with SSL and gzip directly to the web container, keeping focus on my original point to be sure that you follow best practices and keep software up to date. You won't be able to account for everything in the end, yet it sounds like you're off to a great start with this research.

Comment: We went with Tomcat. Thanks! (Compression disabled, SSL with the SSL provider which only has crypto primitives implemented in C - most importantly all of SSL protocol and X509 certificate parsing is pure Java.)

Comment: No problem, good to hear you've made a selection. It definitely sounds like you've minimized your risk. I'd be curious if you discover any further details on web server security, you've helped me learn more too.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something simple and single-purpose, I would **give a try to Grizzly** - less code, less bugs. It has some SSLConfig class to setup HTTPS, altough I have not used it.

Comment: I have tried Grizzly before, and it obviously gets somewhat more exposure than, say, Netty, because it is used in Glassfish. However, I am still unsure if I would achieve better security with it than Tomcat, or something else.

Comment: Yes, I recommend Grizzly because I know how easy it is to implement a simple HTTP server in it. I do not know Netty at all.

Comment: Didn't pick Grizzly because it's not that commonly used and because there is no clear indication that it would be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Most servers are capable of that. Tomcat is an obvious choice. Tomcat behind Apache is also common. If using JavaEE - any application server would work.

Comment: I am well aware that just about all are "capable". However, I'm looking for the one which has the best security record. Apache is obviously extremely common, but it also has a long track record of security vulnerabilities and requires frequent updates to stay secure. Tomcat also has quite a few vulnerabilities triggered by malicious HTTP headers. But I'm not saying that they still couldn't be the best choices compared to the alternatives...